# Instantiate not placing clones at desired place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´m trying to instantiate a clone of a prefab. I pass as parameter the prefab to clone, the position to put it and the rotation. 
The problem is that Unity don't put the clone as the desired position. Any ideas?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemy;

    void Start()
    {
       Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(30, 30, 30), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

[image: Instantiated prefab]

Comment: do you have any script on enemy object?

Comment: @UmairM No, just Transform and Animator

Comment: Strange! disable animator component and try again

Comment: @UmairM That was it! Thanks

Comment: @UmairM Consider adding your comment as an answer so this question can be officially answered. :)